# Equivalence between two comeager sets related to free groups

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, free-groups, baire-category

Let $G$ be a non discrete Polish group. For every $n\ge 2$ equip $G^n$ with the product topology.

Saying that $F_n=\{(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in G^n: \{g_1,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of rank $n$} is comeager in $G^n$ is equivalent to say that $F'_n=\{(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in G^n: \{g_1,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of rank at most $n$} is comeager in $G^n$ ?

Since $F_n\subseteq F_n'$ we have that if $F_n$ is comeager that $F'_n$ is comeager too.

My problem is the other implication. My intuitive idea is the following: suppose $F'_n$ is comeager and take $(g_1,...,g_n)\in F'_n$ such that $\{g_1,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of rank$<n$, say $n-1$ for example. So there are two elements $g_i$ in $(g_1,...,g_n)$ which are equal. Suppose $g_1=g_2$. My hope would be that there is a tuple $(h_1,g_2,...,g_n)\in G^n$ such that $\{h_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of rank $n$. So this tuple would be in $F_n$ and maybe it might be helpful to deduce that also $F_n$ is comeager.

Observe that if $\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of rank $n$ then $\{g_2,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of rank $n-1$.

Warning: before reading the answer, it might be helpful to look at this: [If I say $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ freely generates a subgroup of $G$, does that mean the elements $g_i$ are all distinct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1675109)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta\subset G^n$ be the set of points whose coordinates are not all distinct.  As you observe, $F'_n\setminus F_n\subseteq\Delta$.  But $\Delta$ is meager: for each pair of distinct $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, the set of points $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ with $g_i=g_j$ is clearly closed and has empty interior since $G$ is not discrete, and $\Delta$ is the union of these sets over the finitely many such pairs $(i,j)$.  So if $F'_n$ is comeager, so is $F_n=F'_n\setminus\Delta$.

Comment: sorry could you give me more details about the fact that the set of points $(g_1,...,g_n)$ with $g_i\not=g_j$ is closed and has empty interior ? thank you very much

Comment: Oops, I meant $g_i=g_j$.  Hopefully that should make more sense now.

Comment: The logic reasoning is correct now but actually I still can't see why that set is closed and has empty interior, in particular the latter... thank you

Comment: If you have a sequence of points for which $g_i=g_j$, then the limit also satisfies $g_i=g_j$.  If you have a point with $g_i=g_j$ and any open neighborhood $U=\prod U_k$ of it, then since $G$ is not discrete, $U_i$ and $U_j$ have more than one point, so we can pick a point in $U$ whose $i$ coordinate and $j$ coordinates are not equal.

Comment: got it, thank you very much. In your opinion, can we extend this result for $F_\infty$ and $F'_\infty$ where this time we have sequences $(g_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\{g_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ freely generate a free subgroup of rank countably infinite/at most countably infinite? If you want I can edit the question adding this.

Comment: Yes, the same argument should apply ($\Delta$ is still a union of countably many closed sets with no interior).

Comment: But there wouldn't be a problem because in the case of $F_\infty$ this time not all the terms of the sequences are distinct? I mean a sequence in $F_\infty$ may have a finite number of equal components but at the same time it may freely generate a free subgroup of rank countably infinite..

Comment: But $F'_\infty\setminus F_\infty$ is still contained in $\Delta$, which is meager.

Comment: Last thing: so $F'_\infty\setminus F_\infty\subseteq \Delta$ but at the same time $F_\infty\supseteq F'_\infty\setminus\Delta$ right? And the other inclusion is not correct..

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Eric-wofsey I edited your post by adding a blank character just to be able to upvote your answer that I had previously downvoted (wrongly believing it was incorrect).  Please see [get rid of “vote locking”](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/please-get-rid-of-vote-locking?lq=1) for the technical aspect.

Comment: @EricWofsey Please I would be glad if you take a look at this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864156/about-an-article-regarding-free-groups that is strictly related to this one. I think I really need your help.