# Free groups and words

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups, free-groups

I am currently reading this paper https://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/35/5/624.abstract and I have some difficulties to understand two steps of the proof of the main theorem.

Let $G$ be a non discrete topological group.

First of all, the authors indicate by $w(X_1,...,X_n)$ a free word. They don't say what it means exactly but I suppose the correct definition is the following:

$\textbf {Definition}$ A free word $w(X_1,...,X_n)$ is a function $w:G^n\to G$ such that $w(X_1,...,X_n)=X_{i_1}^{a_1}...X_{i_k}^{a_k}$ where $k\ge 1$, $i_1,...,i_k\in \{1,...,n\}$ and $a_1,...,a_k$ are integers different from $0$.

Now define for every $n\ge 2$: $F_n=\{ (g_1,...,g_n) \in G^n: \{g_1,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of G}, $F_\infty=\{(g_i)_1^\infty \in G^\infty: \{g_i\}_1^\infty $freely generates a free subgroup of G }

$\textbf {Warning}$ The ranks of the free groups generated by the elements of $F_n$ and $F_\infty$ are respectively $\textbf {at most } n$ and $\textbf{at most } \infty$. About this see [If I say $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ freely generates a subgroup of $G$, does that mean the elements $g_i$ are all distinct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675109/if-i-say-g-1-dots-g-n-freely-generates-a-subgroup-of-g-does-that-mean)

Now for every word $w$ define $C(w)=\{(g_1,...,g_n)\in G^n: w(g_1,...,g_n)=1\}$ and for every $n$-uple$ K=(k_1,...,k_n) $, where $ k_i$ are naturals,define $C(w,K)=\{(g_i)_1^\infty \in G^\infty: w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1 $and the $g_{k_j} $are all distinct}.

$\textbf {Problem 1} $Prove that $F_n=G^n\setminus\bigcup_w C(w)$

$\textbf {Problem 2}$ Prove that $F_\infty=G^\infty\setminus\bigcup_{w,K} C(w,K)$

I know that the idea is that if the word is $1$ then we can in some way deny the definition of free group but I need your help for the details.

Comment: If for example $\;g_1=g_2\;$ then the *reduced* word $\;g_1g_2^{-1}=1\;$ , which means the group fulfills a non-trivial relation on its generatos and it thus cannot be free on them.

Comment: About your comment, please see the linked question.

Comment: Well, up to some agreement in the objections that were rised there, I'd say it still follows that we're assuming the elements $\;g_i\;$ to be different, otherwise things could be too heavy imo.

Comment: Indeed, but I think the authors do not consider the $g_i$ distinct and so I need help exactly because the things are heavy.

Comment: The paper is 14 years old. Odds are at least one of the authors is still alive. Have you considered writing them/him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Warning: I do not have access to the article itself and am basing everything below only on what you have written.]

First, a minor point: your definition of "free word" isn't quite right: you need to also require that $i_j\neq i_{j+1}$ for each $j$.

In context it seems clear that $F_n$ is meant to be defined as the set of tuples $(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in G^n$ such that $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ freely generates a subgroup *and* the $g_i$ are all distinct (that is, in the language of my answer to the previous question, $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ freely generates a subgroup).  Indeed, with your interpretation the claim is not true: if for instance $g\in G$ generates a free subgroup then $(g,g)$ would be in $F_2$ by your interpretation, but it is in $C(w)$ where $w(X_1,X_2)=X_1X_2^{-1}$.

With the interpretation that the $g_i$ must all be distinct, the claim is easy to prove.  Indeed, fix $(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in G^n$ and let $H$ be the free group on generators $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  There is then a unique homomorphism $\varphi:H\to G$ that sends $x_i$ to $g_i$.  Since $H$ is freely generated by the $x_i$, each free word on the $x_i$ is a non-identity element of $H$ (and conversely each non-identity element of $H$ can be represented uniquely as a free word on the $x_i$).  Since $\varphi(w(x_1,\dots,x_n))=w(g_1,\dots,x_n)$, the set of non-identity elements of the kernel of $\varphi$ is in bijection with the set of $w$ such that $(g_1,\dots,g_n)\in C(w)$.  But $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ freely generates a subgroup iff $\varphi$ is injective (and hence an isomorphism between $H$ and the subgroup generated by the $g_i$).  Thus $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ freely generates a subgroup iff it is not in any $C(w)$.

For $F_\infty$, your interpretation does make the equation $F_\infty=G^\infty\setminus\bigcup_{w,K} C(w,K)$ true, since the definition of $C(w,K)$ only considers the case that the $g_{k_j}$ are all distinct. However, it seems rather strange to me that this would be intended.  I would guess that the definition of $F_\infty$ is meant to require the $g_i$ to all be distinct, and that in defining $C(w,K)$ you should require the $k_j$ to be distinct rather than the $g_{k_j}$.  With this interpretation, the proof of the second claim is nearly identical to the proof of the first claim: you now take $H$ to be free on $x_1,x_2,\dots$, and define $\varphi:H\to G$ sending $x_i$ to $g_i$.  For any $(w,K)$ (with the $k_j$ all distinct), the element $w(x_{k_1},\dots,x_{k_n})\in H$ is not the identity (and conversely every non-identity element of $H$ has a unique representation of this form).  So there is a nontrivial element of the kernel of $\varphi$ iff there is a $w$ and $K$ such that $(g_i)\in C(w,K)$.

Alternatively, it is plausible that actually your interpretation is the intended one for both the $F_n$ and for $F_\infty$, in which case the definition of $C(w)$ should be changed to require that for all $i$ such that $X_i$ appears in $w$, the $g_i$ are distinct.  I can't say for sure without seeing the context in the article.

Comment: I really thank you for your help. I really need it. However I still have some doubts. 1) In order to have uniqueness of representation as free word,is my definition ok or should I add that $X_{i_j}\not=X_{i_{j+1}}$? 2) About the infinity case, if I consider the $g_i$ as not distinct, what is a counterexample? The $\infty$-uple $(g,g,....)$ does not work because of the definition of $C(w,K)$. Moreover note that we can have the situation where some $g_i$ are equal but at the same time the set of all the $g_i$ still generates a free subgroup of infinity rank.

Comment: Personally I prefer an edited answer instead of comments if it is possible. Thank you again

Comment: The context is about "almost freeness". They also extended a result by Dixon, who studied the finite case and actually he said explicitly that the rank of the elements of $F_n$ must be $n$. I copied the definitions from the article ( also C(w) and C(w,K)). So I'd say to use the interpretations that make the two claims true. We are ok for the finite case.For the infinity, so the intepretation is: the elements of $F_\infty$ generate a free subgroup of rank at most $\infty$, right? So in theory also finite rank can be obtained. I m sorry but I need to ask you how can I prove the second claim?

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how to modify your proof of the finite case. Moreover, what if the correct intepretation is that the elements of $F_\infty$ generate a subgroup of rank $\infty$ but they are not necessarily all distinct ? Does the claim hold ? Thank you for your help. I hope this is my last question.

Comment: I cannot see any reasonable tweak of the definitions such that the second claim would be true if $F_\infty$ is supposed to be the set of (not necessarily distinct) tuples that generate a subgroup of rank $\infty$.

Comment: 1) Without changing the definitions, do you have a counterexample about your comment? 2) the interpretation of $F_\infty$ Is the one of my third comment right? 3) in your proof you said that the claim is true for the interpretation given in my third comment but then you changed the definition of C(w,K). What is the proof without this changement ? I m sorry but i wouldn t change the definition if not strictly necessary

Comment: 1) With the original definition of $C(w,K)$, $(g,g,\dots)$ is in $G^\infty\setminus\bigcup_{w,K} C(w,K)$ for any non-identity $g\in G$.  2) What I referred to as "your interpretation" in the answer is that $F_\infty$ is the set of tuples such that the set $\{g_i\}$ freely generates a subgroup.  3) If you don't change the definition of $C(w,K)$, you just get that the changed $C(w,K)$ condition holds when applied to the tuple obtained from $(g_i)$ by removing all duplicates.  By my proof in the answer, this holds iff that tuple freely generarates a subgroup.

Comment: Changing the definition may not be "strictly necessary" for this particular claim, but it surely is necessary for much of the rest of the article.

Comment: In order to finish: 1) For "my interpretation" , and so with the original definition of C(w,K), the claim is true. The proof is still your second one or I need to modify it? 2)with the original definition of C(w,K) and with the interpretation of the set of the tuples not necessarily distinct and that generates a subgroup of rank infty we have the counterexample $(g,g,...)$. 3) with your interpretation namely the $g_i$ are distinct, we need to modify the definition of C(w,K). If not the claim is true only deleting the duplicte in $g_i$. Do you have a counterexample also for this case?

Comment: 4) moreover I really don t understand in your proof where you used the fact that the $k_j$ are all distinct. Probably when you said for any (w,K) you already considered the components of K distinct?

Comment: Probably this can help to clarify which is the right interpretation of $F_\infty$ and the right definition of C(w,K).The authors also say that $C(w,K)=\pi_K^{-1}[C(w)\cap G^{(n)}]$ where $\pi_K(g_1,g_2,...)=(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})$ and $G^{(n)}$ is the set of the n-uple $(g_1,...,g_n)$ such that all the $g_i$ are distinct.

Comment: 5) Actually with this equation it seems to me that we need the original definition of C(w,K). I don't think your mew definition makes the equation true.

Comment: I thank you again for your help and I hope you can help me to solve these last doubts

Comment: 1) The proof is the proof I sketched in part 3) of my previous comment.  3) Consider an infinite set that freely generates a subgroup but has duplicates. 4) Yes, I've edited to say this.  If you don't require the $k_j$ to be distinct, it's not true that $w(x_{k_1},\dots,x_{k_n})$ is never the identity.

Comment: 5) That's correct, the equation $C(w,K)=\pi_K^{-1}[C(w)\cap G^{(n)}]$ is only true for the original definition of $C(w,K)$.  Nevertheless, I still seriously doubt that this is what the authors really meant, since the corresponding definition of $F_\infty$ is quite unnatural and not analogous with the definition of $F_n$ that makes the first claim true. For what it's worth, while I can't access the paper in question, in the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1099.pdf that appears to build on its results I can definitely say that my interpretation is the intended one.

Comment: 1) So about your definition, in the article you linked to me, consider definition 2. Do you agree that the author forgot to say that $i_1,...,i_n$ must be all distinct in order to define $C^k(w)$? (See also the lemma below, the observation in the third sentence) 2) About the last equation, I have a serious problem now because the equation is fundamental to prove that $C(w,K)$ is an $F_\sigma$ set. ($C(w)\cap G^{(n)}$ is clearly an $F_\sigma$ and $\pi_K$ is continuous). How can we fix it ?

Comment: 1) Yes, either that or they consider that part of their definition of "free word" (note that they don't include the variable tuple as part of their notation $C^\kappa(w)$, so they seem to be considering the variable tuple itself as part of the meaning of "$w$").  2) By my definition, $C(w,K)$ is $\pi^{-1}_K(C(w))$, which is clearly still $F_\sigma$ (in fact, it's closed).  I'm also saying you should only consider the $C(w,K)$s for which all the $k_j$ are distinct, but that doesn't change the fact that each individual one is $F_\sigma$.

Comment: Sorry but by your definition I meant that all the $g_i$ in $ F_\infty$ are all distinct and that the C(w,K)s must be considered with the new definition, namely the $k_j$ are distinct. So why in this case every C(w,K) is an $F_\sigma$ ? After this I suppose I have finished.

Comment: If also in this final case, in your opinion we have $C(w,K)=\pi_K^{-1}(C(w))$ I would be glad if you could give me a detailed final proof. Thank you very much

Comment: That is what I meant by "my definition" in my previous comment.  In that case, $C(w,K)=\pi^{-1}_K(C(w))$, because I've removed the condition that the $g_{k_j}$ are all distinct from the definition of $C(w,K)$ (and replaced it with the restriction that we will only consider pairs $(w,K)$ for which the $k_j$ are distinct).

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Give me some time to reorganize the ideas and then I will mark your answer.

Comment: Sorry but why we really need in the definition of free word that the $i_j\not=i_{j+1}$ ? I mean, defining a free word as function, we have that the function $X_1X_1^2$ is equal to the function $X_1^3$. More generally I can't see the problem to have two different free words for the same element of H . What is my mistake ?

Comment: You need free words to always evaluate to something other than the identity if you plug in free generators.  The word $X_1X_1^{-1}$ fails this, for instance.

Comment: Ok but this is a reasonable advice, right? I mean, does your proof fail if I do not consider $i_j\not=i_{j+1}$? For me no because the uniqueness of representation of the  elements of H as free words would be still respected. Am I wrong?

Comment: Of course I m referring to non identity elements of H

Comment: If $X_1X_1^{-1}$ counts as a free word, then _any_ tuple is in $C(X_1X_1^{-1})$, so $G^n\setminus\bigcup_w C(w)$ would be empty.  My proof breaks down because you need to know that $w(x_1,\dots,x_n)\neq 1$ in $H$ for any $w$ in order to obtain a nontrivial element of the kernel of $\varphi$.

Comment: Oh, ok. So I was right that the uniqueness of representation for non identity elements of H holds even with the wrong definition of free word, wasn t I? The point was about not to make the identity constanct function a free word. Tell me if you don't agree about these two considerations.

Comment: please see my answer below. Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, real last question: you said that with the original definition of $F_\infty$ and the original definition of C(w,K) the equation of the second claim is true. How the proof proceed in that case? I mean directly by double inclusion or more like the proofs tht we have already done?

Comment: Moreover do you agree that in my Prop 3 we really need that in definition of $\pi_K$ all the $k_j$ must be distinct? In particular only in the second inclusion.

Comment: The proof that the second claim is true for the original definitions is very similar to the proof that it is true with my definitions.  You just want to make $H$ be free on a set $\{x_i\}$ you get by removing all the $x_i$ which correspond to $g_i$ that are "duplicates".  In your Prop 3, it is not necessary for the $k_j$ to be distinct.

Comment: About the second claim: what is the bijection in this case? Don't we risk to make the equation true only for the tuples without duplicates?About prop 3: why not? In the second inclusion we have that $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$ implies $(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})\in C(w,K)$ only if the $k_j$ are distinct, namely only if $\pi_K$ is defined for $k_j$ distinct. To be sure:about prop 3 I was using your definitions.

Comment: Do you have some ideas for these questions? Unfortunately I can't see how to solve them. Thank you  for your patience.

Comment: The equation only needs to be true for tuples without duplicates, because for tuples with duplicates $(g_i)$ automatically can't be in $C(w,K)$.  For prop 3 I'm not sure what you're saying.  Obviously for the statement to be true for the $k_j$ not distinct you should define $C(w,K)$ in those cases (just don't include those cases in the statement of Prop 2).

Answer (score 0):

To Eric Wofsey: this answer needs to me to see if I have understood everything of your ideas. Please tell me if there are some mistakes in proofs or definitions and feel free to edit my answer or to make corrections. I put some questions at the end. $\textbf{The first one is fundamental for me}$. After your answers and corrections I will mark your answer as the official one.

$\textbf{Def 1}$ A free word is a function $w:G^n\to G$ such that $w(X_1,...,X_n)=X_{i_1}^{a_1}...X_{i_k}^{a_k}$ with $k\ge 1, a_1,...,a_k$ are integers different from $0$, $i_1,...,i_k\in \{1,...,n\}$ and $i_j\not=i_{j+1}$ for every $j$

$\textbf{Def 2}$ For every $n\ge 2$ let $F_n=\{ (g_1,...,g_n) \in G^n: \{g_1,...,g_n\}$ freely generates a free subgroup of G and all the $g_i$ are distinct}

$\textbf{Def 3} F_\infty=\{(g_i)_1^\infty \in G^\infty: \{g_i\}_1^\infty $freely generates a free subgroup of G and all the $g_i$ are distinct}

$\textbf{Def 4}$ For every free word $w$ define $C(w)=\{(g_1,...,g_n)\in G^n: w(g_1,...,g_n)=1\}$

$\textbf{Def 5}$ For every $n$-uple $K=(k_1,...,k_n) $, where $k_i$ are strictly positive integers and $\textbf{all distinct},$ define $C(w,K)=\{(g_i)_1^\infty \in G^\infty: w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1 $}.

$\textbf{Def 6}$ For every $n$-uple$ K=(k_1,...,k_n) $ with the $k_j$ $\textbf{all distinct}$, define $\pi_K(g_1,g_2,...)=(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})$

$\textbf {Prop 1}$ $F_n=G^n\setminus\bigcup_w C(w)$

Proof. Fix $(g_1,...,g_n)\in G^n$. Let $H$ be the free group of rank $n$ and generators $x_1,...,x_n$. Then there exists a unique isomorphism $f:H\to G $ such that it send every $x_i$ in $g_i$.

$\textbf{Notation}$ I will indicate by $w'$ the free words defined on $H^n$ and by $w$ the "same" words defined on $G^n$ ( I mean replacin $h_i$ by $g_i$). I will indicate by $T*$ the set $T$ minus the identity.

By definition of free group, we know that for every element in $H*$ there exists a unique free word $w'_h$ such that $w'_h(x_1,...,x_n)=h$. Note also that $f(h)=f(w'_h(x_1,...,.x_n))=w_h(g_1,...,g_n)$.

$\textbf{Fact 1}$ $\alpha:ker f*\to \{w':(g_1,...,g_n)\in C(w)\}=M$ such that $\alpha(t)=w'_t$ is a bijection

It is easy to prove that $\alpha$ is well defined, namely that $\alpha(t)\in M$

Surjectivity: Let $w'\in M$. We have $w(g_1,...,g_n)=1$. Let $t=w'(x_1,...,x_n)$. By definition of free word and free group, we have that $w'(x_1,...,x_n)\not=1$ and $f(w'(x_1,...,x_n))=w(g_1,...,g_n)=1$, namely $t\in ker f*$. By construction and uniqueness we have $\alpha(t)=\alpha(w'(x_1,...,x_n))=w'.$

Injectivity: $\alpha(t_1)=\alpha(t_2)$ iff $w'_{t_1}=w'_{t_2}$ iff $t_1=t_2$ by the uniqueness of representation of the $t_i$ as free words.

$\textbf{Fact 2}$ $(g_1,...,g_n)\in F_n$ iff $f$ is injective

Indeed: if $(g_1,...,g_n)\in F_n$ then the $g_i$ are all distinct and for every $w$ we have $w(g_1,...,g_n)\not =1$. Hence $ ker f*=\{h\in H*:f(h)=1\}=\{h\in H*: f(w'_h(x_1,...,x_n))=1\}=\{h\in H*:w_h(g_1,...,g_n)=1\}=\emptyset$.

On the other hand, if $f$ is injective, then the $g_i$ are all distinct and $H$ is isomorphic to $Im f$. So $Im f$ is the free group of rank $n$. Moreover generators are sent to generators, so the $g_1$ generate $Im f$. Note that $Im f*=\{w_h(g_1,...,g_n):h=w'_h(x_1,...,x_n)\in H*\}$ and if $h_1\not=h_2$ then $w_{h_1}(g_1,...,g_n)\not=w_{h_2}(g_1,...,g_n)$ since $f$ is injective. So by definition of free group we have that $Im f$ is free on the $g_1$.

Now $(g_1,...,g_n)\in F_n$ iff $f$ is injective iff $ker f *=\emptyset=M$ iff $(g_1,...,g_n)$ is not in $C(w)$ for every free word $w$, namely the thesis.

$\textbf {Prop 2}$ $F_\infty=G^\infty\setminus\bigcup_{w,K}C(w,K)$

Proof. Fix $(g_i)\in G^\infty$. Let $H$ be the free group of rank $|\mathbb N|$ on the generators $x_1,x_2,...$. Then there exists a unique homomorphism $f:H\to G$ such that $f(x_i)=g_i$. Moreover we know that for every $h\in H*$ there exists a unique $(w_h,K_h)$ with the $k_j$ all distinct such that $w'_h(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_n})=h$.

$\textbf {Notation}$ Same of the previous proposition and $(g_i)_1^\infty=(g_i)$.

$\textbf {Fact 3}$ $\alpha:ker f*\to \{(w',K):(g_i)\in C(w,K)\}=N$ such that $t\mapsto (w'_t,K_t)$ is a bijection.

It is easy to prove that $\alpha$ is well defined, namely that $\alpha(t)\in N$

Surjectivity: Let $(w',K)\in N$. Now $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$ with the $k_j$ distinct. Let $t=w'(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_n})$. We have $t\not=1$ and $f(t)=w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$, namely $t\in ker f*$ and clearly $\alpha(t)=(w',K)$.

Injectivity: $\alpha(t_1)=\alpha(t_2)$ iff $(w'_{t_1},K_{t_1})=(w'_{t_2},K_{t_2})$ iff $K_{t_1}=K_{t_2}$ and $w'_{t_1}=w'_{t_2}$. By the uniqueness of the couples $(w'_{t_i}, K_{t_i})$ we have $t_1=t_2$.

$\textbf {Fact 4}$ $(g_i)\in F_\infty$ iff $f$ is injective

Indeed: if $(g_i)\in F_\infty$ then all the $g_i$ are distinct and for every $(w,K)$ with the $k_j$ all distinct we have $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})\not =1$. So $ker f*=\{h=w'_h(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_n})\in H*:f(h)=w_h(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$ and all the $k_j$ are distinct}$=\emptyset$, which implies $f$ is injective.

On the other hand, if $f$ is injective then all the $g_i$ are distinct and $H$ is isomorphic to $Im f$, so $Im f$ is the free group of rank $|\mathbb N|$. It is also generated by the $g_i$ and note that $Im f*=\{w_h(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n}):h=w'_h(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_n})\in H*$ with all the $k_j$ distinct} and that if $h_1\not=h_2$ then $w_{h_1}(g_{s_1},...,g_{s_n})\not=w_{h_2}(g_{r_1},...,g_{r_n})$, since $f$ is injective (and with the $s_i$ distinct and $r_j$ distinct). So by definition of free group, we deduce that $Im f$ is free on the $g_i$.

Finally we have that $(g_i)\in F_\infty$ iff $f$ is injective iff $ker f*=\emptyset=N$ iff $(g_i)$ is not in $C(w,K)$ for every free word $w$ and every $K$ with the $k_j$ all distinct.

$\textbf {Prop 3}$ $ C(w,K)=\pi_K^{-1}(C(w))$.

Proof. Consider $(g_i)\in C(w,K)$. Then there exists (w,K) with the $k_j$ distinct such that $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$. On the other hand $\pi_K(g_i)=(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})$ and so we have an inclusion. For the other one, note that if $(g_i)\in \pi_K^{-1}(C(w))$ then $\pi_K(g_i)=(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})\in C(w)$ and so $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$ and we have the thesis since the $k_j$ are distinct.

$\textbf{Questions}$ 1) If I consider the definition of $F_\infty$ of this answer but the original definition of C(w,K), namely all the $g_{k_i}$ are distinct which part of my proof breaks down? Note that $g_{k_i}$ distinct implies $k_i$ distinct. Do you have a counterexample about this? 2) If I want $\pi_K$ to be an open function, is it important to require in its definition that all the $k_j$ are distinct?

Comment: @Eric wofsey please see this answer. Thank you very much

Comment: 1) Fact 3 can fail.  Indeed, $\alpha(t)$ need not even be an element of $N$ for every $t\in\ker(f*)$.  If $g_i=g_j$, then $t=x_ix_j^{-1}$ is in $\ker(f*)$ but $\alpha(t)$ is not in $N$. 2) Yes.  If $k_i=k_j$, then the image of $\pi_K$ is contained in the set of points whose $i$th coordinate equals their $j$th coordinate, which has empty interior if $G$ has no isolated points.

Comment: 1)Why not? Consider $K=(i,j)$ and note that $w'_t=w_t=X_iX_j^{-1}$. We have that $w_t(g_j,g_i)=1$, namely $(w'_t,K)\in N$. 2) In your comments you said that with the original definition prop 3 fails. Were you wrong? 3) do you agree with the proofs and definitions of my answer?

Comment: 1) By definition of $C(w,K)$, $(g_i)$ cannot be in $C(w,K)$ if $g_i=g_j$.  2) Prop 3 does indeed fail with the orignal definition. 3) They look correct, though I may have overlooked a small detail or two.

Comment: 1)sorry why not? You just need that in K the indices are distinct and we actually have $i\not =j$. Moreover the evaluation through $w$ is $1$. Could you give me more details please? 2) which part of the prop 3 fails and why?

Comment: Read the original definition of $C(w,K)$.  By definition, $(g_i)$ cannot be in $C(w,K)$ unless the $g_{k_j}$ are all distinct.  This fact also breaks the proof of Prop 3.

Comment: Confirmation about prop 3: first inclusion would fail because $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$ will not imply that $(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})\in C(w)$ and similarly the second inclusion would fail because $w(g_{k_1},...,g_{k_n})=1$ will not imply that $(g_i)\in C(w,K)$. Do you agree?

Comment: Sorry the first inclusion would hold, actually. The second inclusion would fail for the reason of my previous comment. (If for example $g_{k_1}=g_{k_2}$). Do you agree?

Comment: That's correct.  The first inclusion works but the second inclusion fails.